# Data-Migration-Tool doesn't migrate utf-8 characters (Magento 2)

Tags: database, magento2-migration-tool, utf-8

I use the second step of migration with data-migration-tool 2.0.2 in plain Magento 2.0.4.

```
php bin/magento migrate:data {config.xml}
```

Its successfully completed. 
But it doesn't migrate utf-8 characters from older Magento1-database to my Magento2-database. Both databases have the collation "utf8_general_ci".

For example in Magento1-database in product table is the value "Maße ..." but in Magento2-database is only "Ma" because of the utf-8 character "ß". The rest of text in this value seems to be cut off. So I see in admin in *Products->Catalog* also only "Ma" in this product.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Data-Migration-Tool does not receive data from the source in utf8.
[Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92578/data-migration-eav-step-error/124711#124711) is a simple solution to this problem