# Data migration Eav step error - duplicate

Tags: migration, magento2.3.5, magento-1.9.4

Anyone having this issue?

data migration > EAV Step

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '9-product-details' for key 'EAV_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_CODE'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check this link :- **https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/235#issuecomment-321923437**

> Solution is to rename all values containing the name "Default" in "attribute_value_name" field of eav_attribute_set table to "Default_x" in the Magento 1 database and run the migration from scratch.

> In my case, there were 9 records with name "Default". So I renamed them to Default_1 to Default_9 and it worked perfectly!

check this :- **https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/158788/85907**

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Comment: I have try sql UPDATE eav_attribute_group SET attribute_group_name = CONCAT(attribute_group_name, "_", attribute_set_id) WHERE attribute_group_name = "General"; and it work, Thank you!

Comment: Sound good, welcome @David ...