# MAGENTO2 - SQLSTATE[23000]:Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1486-1420'

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

Hi I am doing migration activity from magento version 1.9.0.1 to Magento 2.3.5 using default migration. I have success fully done the migration of the settings part. I am performing the migration for the data and facing the below error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1486-1420' for key 'CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_TO_ENTT_VAL_ID_ENTT_ID'
```

Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/98071/85907

Comment: Please check this --> https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Version-Upgrades/Migration-issue-from-1-9-to-2-2-6/td-p/113107

Comment: Another resource for your solution: https ://firebearstudio.com/blog/magento-2-integrity-constraint-violation-issues-solutions.html